# Why we should create default constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, constructor

I am new to C# and I'm following a course instructions, and created a custom constructor to validate the data.

But I'm wondering: why should we create a default constructor for our class?

This is my code :

```
public class UserNotification
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order =1)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [Key]
    public int NotificationId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public Notification Notification { get; set; }

    public bool IsRead { get; set; }

    protected UserNotification(){ }

    public UserNotification(ApplicationUser user, Notification notification)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }

        if (notification == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("notification");
        }

        Notification = notification;
        User = user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the default constructor is used when you query the db and objects are materialized. What values should EF pass to your constructor when you query the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why should we create a default constructor for our class?

There is no general rule, that you have to create a default constructor. But if you use entity framework, you need an empty constructor because entity framework needs it.

In general, the ecosystem moves away from empty default constructors. Reasons are non nullable properties and immutable data structures, but again - as of today entity framework does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

In this use case, it is beneficial for you to define the empty constructor. By default, C# has a `public` empty constructor. This constructor can be overridden by simply defining a new empty constructor.

In this code you have here, you define the empty constructor with `protected` access. This (I assume) is because you cannot create an instance of the aforementioned class without any arguments. So, defining the empty constructor as `protected` disallows anyone from implicitly constructing or constructing the class with no arguments.

So, in this case, this code should not compile, with you defining the constructor the way you have:

```cs
UserNotification notification = new UserNotification();
```

However, if you didn't define the empty constructor, it *would* compile and would possibly cause undefined behavior.

Comment: That default constructor is only added when you don't provide any constructor yourself

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes, that's what I said.